# Какой тип сервера или хостинга нужен для развертки git - сервиса на нем?

Tags: git, сервер

Нужно развернуть свой сервер для git. Сейчас в проекте используется GOGS, он стоит у меня на машине. Но из-за расположения, плюс не хочу свой комп нагружать 24 на 7. Решил перекинуть репозиторий с проектом на какой-нибудь хостинг/сервер. Пока гуглил нашел предложение по поводу виртуального сервера.

Бюджет у меня небольшой, около 500 рублей в месяц. Какой тип сервера или хостинга(я не совсем понимаю мат часть данного вопроса) нужно выбрать, чтобы на нем можно было развернуть какой-нибудь git -сервис. Чтобы в него загрузить проект(около 50гб) и можно было загружать/выкачивать в него файлы.Также, чтобы доступ можно было давать либо по http либо по ssh. Сейчас в gogs, люди имеют доступ к репозиторию по моему белому IP.

Также, какие моменты стоит учитывать

Comment: не проще ли на том же гитхабе платный аккаунт завести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, я рекомендую вам обратиться к системным требованиям Gitea (как пример):

```
 - A Raspberry Pi 3 is powerful enough to run Gitea for small workloads.
 - 2 CPU cores and 1GB RAM is typically sufficient for small teams/projects.
 - Gitea should be run with a dedicated non-root system account on UNIX-type systems. 
 - Note: Gitea manages the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Running Gitea as a regular user could break that user’s ability to log in.
 - Git version 1.7.2 or later is required. Version 1.9.0 or later is recommended. Also please note: 
 - Git large file storage will be available if enabled when git >= 2.1.2.
 - Git commit-graph rendering will be enabled automatically when git >= 2.18
```

Исходя из этого можно смело приобрести:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из своего опыта - у меня есть OrangePi PC работающий на ARMBian на котором запущена Gitea и пользуются ей 7 человек. Говоря коротко - pull, push и работа с проектом в браузере это не то, что заставляет нас страдать.

Comment: А теперь добавьте 50 ГБ, о которых говорит автор, и скажите новую цену.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler 845р. В перспективе, я думаю выгоднее приобрести одноплатник + карту памяти.

Comment: "Бюджет у меня небольшой, около 500 рублей в месяц." - слова автора. Я думаю, стоит поискать сервис подешевле, и вполне себе можно найти

Comment: raspberry pi или аналоги очень хорошо справятся с такой задачей (главное диск поставить нормальный) до тех пор пока не нужно будет сделать какой-нибудь CI/CD. А если коммитить/пушить, то тут и два десятка пользователей не будет проблемой (ну если только не навешать кучу хуков)